# Custom CommandBar to PickerFlyout

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, flyout, commandbar

By default `PickerFlyout` has `commandbar` that has done and cancel buttons. Is it possible to disable done button programmatically? If not is there any way to add custom command bar and replace default one?

With the help of the answer given i tried to write custom picker from PickerFlyoutBase. But now i'm not able to add content to flyout  in xaml. Giving me error saying    **custompicker doesnt support direct content**

```
<Button>
     <Button.Flyout>
                        <local:custompicker>
                            <TextBlock Margin="20" FontSize="30" Text="MyPickerFlyout Test" />
                        </local:custompicker>

                    </Button.Flyout>
    </Button


 public class custompicker:PickerFlyoutBase
        {
            private AppBar OriginalAppBar;

        private CommandBar MyCommandBar;

        private Page CurrentPage;

        public custompicker()
        {
            var cancelButton = new AppBarButton();
            cancelButton.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel);
            cancelButton.Label = "Cancel";
            cancelButton.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.Hide();
            };

            MyCommandBar = new CommandBar();
            MyCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(cancelButton);

            this.Closed += MyPickerFlyout_Closed;
            this.Opening += MyPickerFlyout_Opening;
            this.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutPlacementMode.Full;
        }

        private void MyPickerFlyout_Opening(object sender, object e)
        {
            CurrentPage = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page;
            if (CurrentPage != null)
            {
                OriginalAppBar = CurrentPage.BottomAppBar;

                CurrentPage.BottomAppBar = MyCommandBar;
            }
        }

        private void MyPickerFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (CurrentPage != null)
            {
                CurrentPage.BottomAppBar = OriginalAppBar;
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Please note that **PickerFlyout** is not supported for use in UWP apps for Windows 10. Instead, use a [**Flyout**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout) with a custom UI to present a custom picker control.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. I just wanted to know whether  Is it possible in WP 8.1. I dint succeed to implement custom flyout from PickerFlyoutBase also. So if you know please post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PickerFlyout` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pickerflyout) has a [ConfirmationButtonsVisible property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pickerflyout.confirmationbuttonsvisible), we can use this property to disable both "Done" and "Cancel" button.

But there is no way to disable only "Done" button. We have to implement a custom "PickerFlyout". Following is a simple custom "PickerFlyout" based on [`Flyout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout), you can refer to it to implement your own.

```cs
public class MyPickerFlyout : Flyout
{
    private AppBar OriginalAppBar;

    private CommandBar MyCommandBar;

    private Page CurrentPage;

    public MyPickerFlyout()
    {
        var cancelButton = new AppBarButton();
        cancelButton.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Cancel);
        cancelButton.Label = "Cancel";
        cancelButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.Hide();
        };

        MyCommandBar = new CommandBar();
        MyCommandBar.PrimaryCommands.Add(cancelButton);

        this.Closed += MyPickerFlyout_Closed;
        this.Opening += MyPickerFlyout_Opening;
        this.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutPlacementMode.Full;
    }

    private void MyPickerFlyout_Opening(object sender, object e)
    {
        CurrentPage = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Content as Page;
        if (CurrentPage != null)
        {
            OriginalAppBar = CurrentPage.BottomAppBar;

            CurrentPage.BottomAppBar = MyCommandBar;
        }
    }

    private void MyPickerFlyout_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (CurrentPage != null)
        {
            CurrentPage.BottomAppBar = OriginalAppBar;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in XAML like:

```
<Button Content="Show Picker">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <local:MyPickerFlyout Closed="PickerFlyout_Closed">
            <TextBlock Margin="20" FontSize="30" Text="MyPickerFlyout Test" />
        </local:MyPickerFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

And it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. I ll try it. Is it not possible to implement from PickerFlyoutBase  class?

Comment: When i try to implement from PickerFlyoutBase  i was not able to add content to my custom flyout. Why is it? I edited my question. Please have a look into it,tell me what is the problem

Comment: @LovetoCode: I used `Flyout` class for convenience as it already has `Content` property. If you want to use `PickerFlyoutBase` class, you need to implement a property like this and overrid `CreatePresenter` method and `ShouldShowConfirmationButtons` method in your derived class.

Comment: I tried. But dint work.  What i have to implement in CreatePresenter,ShouldShowConfirmationButtons  methods?

Comment: @LovetoCode: `PickerFlyoutBase` class doesn't has `Content` property like `Flyout` class. So you can't set content in XAML directly. Implement from `PickerFlyoutBase` class is a bit more complicated than `Flyout` class. May I know why you want to implement from `PickerFlyoutBase` class?

Comment: Oh. No particular reason. I'm just learning these flyout concepts.

Comment: @LovetoCode: You can try to implement a `Content` property and overrid `CreatePresenter` method and `ShouldShowConfirmationButtons` method in your derived class. If you still encounter problems, you can ask a new question about it. I'll also try to implement a custom flyout from `PickerFlyoutBase` class and update my answer once I finished.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help

Comment: zuo can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770214/wp-8-1-webview-scroll-with-the-page-contents

Comment: Could you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263601/windows-phone-8-1-implement-virtualization-for-custom-variable-sized-gridview?